# Python TikTok API

Tags: python, api, tiktok

How can I get the top 5 most trending tiktoks video urls with the hashtags #techfinds and #tiktiokmademebuyit in python?

Tried

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

# Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uCt1x8kINQ for a brief setup tutorial
with TikTokApi() as api:
  for trending_video in api.trending.videos(count=1):
    # Prints the author's username of the trending video.
    print(trending_video.author.username)
```

not working

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work? is there an error? I'd be surprised if you didn't need any API key to use their service, even if it's free

Comment: @ti7 it is not the official api so i ask if somebody has an official script of the api

Comment: You should have a look at [TikTok API](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-v2-introduction/) then.